# cmake building shared lib from object library results in undefined symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, g++, shared-libraries

I'm building a shared library using cmake. Here are the steps that I take, starting with building a shared library `A_shared` using an object library `A_obj`.

```
add_library(A_obj OBJECT ${A_SRCS})
add_library(A_shared SHARED)
target_link_libraries(A_shared PUBLIC A_obj)
```

This process works. Now I wish to build another shared library that uses `A_shared` and its own sources. So I have:

```
add_library(B_obj OBJECT ${B_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(B_obj PUBLIC A_shared)
add_library(B_shared SHARED)
target_link_libraries(B_shared PUBLIC B_obj)
```

It seems to me that this should be valid, because I'm building objects `B_obj` which have dependence on a shared libraries `A_shared`, and then using these objects to construct shared library `B_shared` and at the same time transitively passing the dependence on `A_shared` using the call to `target_link_libraries`.

However, this results in undefined symbols when building in MSVC. When linking `B_shared.dll`, I get unresolved external dependencies on global variables that were defined in `${A_SRCS}` and used in `${B_srcs}`, and not anything else (like functions). Strangely, the object files `B_obj` compile fine.

- If I instead link `B_shared` to `A_obj`, it works fine. But this gives me the impression that `B_shared` will actually contain the object files from `A_obj`, but all I want it only to link to `A_shared`.
- If I link `B_obj` to `A_obj`, nothing changes and I still get unresolved dependencies.

With gcc, `B_shared` is successfully linked.

Therefore, my question is: am I doing the correct thing in cmake to achieve what I want? I'm wondering what I'm misunderstanding, because I've researched this extensively and I can't find the fault in my process, so I would greatly appreciate any clarification.

Comment: The problem actually comes from the issue brought up here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560832/cmake-windows-export-all-symbols-does-not-cover-global-variables
Even though I am writing `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)`, this doesn't apply to global variables. I have to manually export them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from the behaviour of shared libraries on Windows in general: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560832/cmake-windows-export-all-symbols-does-not-cover-global-variables). I have to manually export the symbols. The interaction with the object library wasn't creating issues.